# How to map 2 inner classes to each other

Tags: java, spring, lambda, mapping, inner-classes

I have 2 classes as A and B. Both of them have inner classes named as C.

```
public class A {
private C classC;

public static C {
private String field1;
private int field2;

//getter and setter for fields
}
//getter and setter for class C
}
```

and same structure for `public class B {...}`

Now I want to map these two C classes to each other in somewhere else like

```
A.setC(B.getC);
```

But the C types are different so I cannot map them. How can I map B.C to A.C ?

Comment: If the inner `C` classes represent the same concept (implied by the fact that you want to assign values mixing the classes) and the same structure (you said so), and don't depend on their enclosing class (they're static), refactor them to become one class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using constructor for mapping `ClassC` between `ClassA` and `Classb`

```
public class ClassA {

  private ClassC classC;

  public static class ClassC {

    private String field1;

    private int feild2;

    public ClassC(ClassB.ClassC classC) {
      this.field1 = classC.field1
      this.feild2 = classC.field2;
     }
   }
 }
```

and then you can map `ClassB.ClassC` to `ClassA.ClassC` or viceversa using constructor `new ClassA.ClassB(classC)`